# Configuring LightDM in Ubuntu GNOME

Tags: lightdm, ubuntu-gnome

I'm currently using Ubuntu GNOME 16.10. I recently replaced GDM with LightDM. But, I noticed that on the login screen, the icons on the top right look a bit bad. Like, the power button looks like an old pc. Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have lightdm-manager installed. If not then install it by a quick "apt-get install"
Then open lightdm-manager and chose from different icons and themes you want.